# Why does this piece of code does not result in my application handling calls?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I am trying to handle calls in my app. I want it to be able to launch an activity when a call (not dial) is made. Nevertheless my app is never suggested when i press the "Call" or phone number buttons in the "People" activity, even if I clear defaults for all similar apps or unistall them.
The code:

```
<!-- ... -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

<!-- ... -->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.contact.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<!-- ... -->
```

I guess I am trying to catch all possible intents related to calling or at least dialing?
So what is wrong?

UPDATE: taping a phone (in an the e-mail app for example) works, but I can't still handle calls from "People".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
<activity
    android:name="com.test.Call"
    android:label="@string/makeCall" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: I did now, that changes nothing apparently.

Answer (score 0):

It always depends on which Intent the calling app is executing. For instance, I wanted to execute my Intent when a user clicks on a phone number in the SMS app. A look to LogCat showed that the following intent is executed by the SMS app:

> 11-24 13:16:57.453: I/ActivityManager(390): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxxxxx cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity (has extras)} from pid 2493

So by adding the following intent filter, it worked for my SMS app:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
```

My advice is to simply use LogCat to find out which intent is expected by the "People" activity.